# Display content from the database when a div with an ID is clicked (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, function

I have a list of divs with unique IDs (they are inserted from my database). When I click on one of them I want to display content from my database in another div. For example, I have a div with class `pizza`. The query should look like this: `SELECT * FROM product WHERE name = 'pizza'`. So depending on what div you click you get different content. The code below doesn't work and is incomplete. I was trying to do some research myself, but I couldn't find anything useful.

```
//head
<script>
$(function () {
        $('.product').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: 'php/recipe-container.php',
                data: new FormData(this),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    $(".display_recipe").html(response);
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });

        });
});
</script>
```

```
//HTML
<div class="product" id="pizza">pizza</div>
<div class="product" id="lasagna">lasagna</div>
<div class="product" id="sushi">sushi</div>

<div class="display_recipe"></div>
```

```
// PHP (recipe-container.php)
<?php

function display_recipe(){
        
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cookbook");
    $product = "'pizza'"; //just a placeholder
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name = $product";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $date = $row['date'];
            
        echo $name;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $description;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $date;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}

display_recipe();
?>
```

Right now when I click the button nothing happens, even "pizza" placeholder doesn't work. Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this even a PHP problem, or a pure JS problem?

Comment: Also, be warned that the query you want to use is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Please have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: Right now it doesn't do any action when I click the div with "product" class. After that I don't know how to make it so it takes div's ID and turns it into a variable, so I can use it in a query. So I have so problems with both PHP and JS.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. "it doesn't do any action" - does that mean the AJAX request is not sent as expected? Or anything else?

Answer (score -1):

JS file (AJAX code)
You can get the id attribute on click of the div with the class 'product' as coded below:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.product').on('click', function (e) {
      var product = jQuery(this).attr('id');

             $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: 'php/recipe-container.php',
                data: {data:product},
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    $(".display_recipe").html(response);
                }
            });
    });
});
```

PHP file: get the posted data in this file use it in a query to fetch the result and return the result to the AJAX success handler as a response.

To fetch the data posted from the ajax in this php file you can use `$_POST['data']` as stated below:

```
$product = $_POST['data'];
```

Use that variable in your sql query to fetch the result and then change the structure of your response as stated below:

```
    //saving the html response in a variable named "response"
    $response = $name.'<br>';
    $response .= $description.'<br>';
    $response .= $date.'<br>';
    //echo response will send the response variable back to the AJAX success handler.
    echo $response;
```

Comment: Please never recommend the usage of insecure SQL queries. The given code is highly vulnerable for SQL injection and should never be used in production!

Comment: Ok making the changes, just tried to help him out with the basic understanding of AJAX

Comment: If the AJAX part is the important one, please explain what you've changed, and why this makes a difference

Comment: Even you can help him out with the SQL injection vulnerabilities

Comment: In the network tab (payload) I get this: [object Object]. Nothing appeared in my div.

Comment: use print_r to view the object @Astw41

Comment: @Astw41 check whether the query is running and you are fetching the required data from the db table. If yes I have created a response variable that you can echo to send back the "HTML" to the AJAX success hander in the form of response.

Comment: @SushantBassi I changed this ``` data: {data:product}, ``` to this ``` data: product, ``` and now i see the correct id name in the network tab. However, content from my database is not displayed at all. Where should I put print_r?

Comment: print_r($res); to see if the query works